Is the Prerequesite of the "Relentless Hex" Invocation to be lvl 7 or to have 7 lvls in Warlock?
The question is basically in the title.
The prerequesites for relentless hex are:

Prerequisites: Level 7+; hex spell or a warlock feature that curses

(Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p.57).
If I now multiclass and have just 1 lvl in Warlock (following the PHB24, I get an Invocation in Warlock at lvl 1), but 6 lvls in another class, could I still pick this Eldritch Invocation?
Another case: I'm a lvl 3 Warlock and lvl 4 other Class, and I take the Eldritch Adept feat as my ASI at lvl 4 of the other class. My overall lvl is 7.
The conditions using the Eldritch Adept feat to take an Eldritch Invocation are:

If the invocation has a prerequisite of any kind, you can choose that invocation only if you're a warlock who meets the prerequisite.
(TCE, p. 79).

In both cases, would I be allowed to take "Relentless Hex", because the prerequisite is being a warlock, and being lvl 7, or am I not allowed, because it needs to be 7 lvls in Warlock?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before.


A level prerequisite refers to your level in this class.

Page 56, second paragraph under the ELDRITCH INVOCATIONS heading.
